# Can I replicate input from one USB port to another?

Tags: usb

I want to set up my RaspPi as a device tethered to my camera. Then I want to connect the Pi to my laptop. When the camera shoots an image, I want the Pi to save it locally then send it on up to the laptop. Ideas?

Comment: "Tethered"? - How exactly is it to be tethered? Which camera are you talking about? - one of the RPi cameras connected via ribbon cable, or a DSLR, or ...?  Details, please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.